# Not getting all form properties using enctype='multipart/form-data'

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express

My NodeJS server uploads files to amazon using a secret form. With that said, I want to add extra security by providing a password field to that form - problem is, when I do that, my server does not get that property when I try to access it through `req.body.pass`

My code:

```
//Express NodeJS Server:

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true 
}));

app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.pass); //undefined, but why? when I remove enctype='multipart/form-data' it works
})

//HTML

<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type="file" name="name" value="">
        <input type="file" name="email" value="">
        <input type="file" name="age" value="">
        <br>Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass"><br>

        <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I remove the following:

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

the field pass works.. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As the `bodyParser` middleware names suggest, they only handle 'application/json' and 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' forms. You will need a separate module to handle `multipart/form-data` forms, such as `multer`.